# Combine multiple tables from db in single view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables in my db.

table 1 structure:

```
date, family, class2, sec2, core1, nlm
```

table 2 structure:

```
date, family, class2, sec2, core2, prefix
```

table 3 structure:

```
date, family, class3, sec3, core3, root
```

I want to create a view combining this three tables.
View will have structure like:

```
date, class, sec, core, group_of_family
```

class is present as class1 in table1, class2 in table 3 and class3 in table3. Same for sec and core.

In the above data one group of date, class, sec and core can be a part of different family like:

table 1 structure:

```
date,       family, class2,    sec2,  core1, nlm
22/7/2020,   f1,       r1,      p1,   xyz, pqr
22/7/2020    f2,       r1,      p1,   xyz, pqrs
24/7/2020    f5,       r2,      p4,   sds, dsg
```

table 2 structure:

```
date,       family, class2,    sec2,  core1, nlm
22/7/2020,   f4,       r1,      p1,   xyz, pqr
24/7/2020    f8,       r6,      p1,   fds, sdg
```

table 3 structure:

```
date,       family, class2,    sec2,  core1, nlm
28/7/2020,   f14,       r1,      p1,   xyz, pqr
24/7/2020    f18,       r6,      p1,   fds, sdg
```

So the view I want should be like this:

```
date,       class,   sec,  core,      group_of_family
22/7/2020,   r1,      p1,   xyz,      f1,f2,f4 
24/7/2020,   r2,      p4,   sds,        f5
24/7/2020,   r6,      p1,   fds,      f8,f18
28/7/2020,   r1,      p1,   xyz,        f14
```

I am new Postgresql db and I don't have much experience in writing complicated queries.

Could someone please help me with the query?
Thanks.

Comment: If any of the following solution has solved your problem then please accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the given data is:

```
create table tbl1
(   
    date date,       
    family text, 
    class2 text,    
    sec2 text,  
    core1 text, 
    nlm text
);

insert into tbl1 values
('2020-07-22','f1','r1','p1','xyz','pqr'),
('2020-07-22','f2','r1','p1','xyz','pqrs'),
('2020-07-24','f5','r2','p4','sds','dsg');

create table tbl2
(   
    date date,       
    family text, 
    class2 text,    
    sec2 text,  
    core1 text, 
    nlm text
);


insert into tbl2 values
('2020-07-22','f4','r1','p1','xyz','pqr'),
('2020-07-24','f8','r6','p1','fds','sdg');

create table tbl3
(   
    date date,       
    family text, 
    class2 text,    
    sec2 text,  
    core1 text, 
    nlm text
);

insert into tbl3 values
('2020-07-28','f14','r1','p1','xyz','pqr'),
('2020-07-24','f18','r6','p1','fds','sdg');
```

Query:

```
create view vw_test as
select date,class,sec,core,string_agg(family,',') as group_of_family
from
(
    select date,class2 as class,
            sec2 as sec,
            core1 as core,
            family
    from tbl1
    union   
    select date,class2 as class,
            sec2 as sec,
            core1 as core,
            family
    from tbl2
    union
    select date,class2 as class,
            sec2 as sec,
            core1 as core,
            family
    from tbl3
)a 
group by date,class,sec,core;
```

Check the expected result:

```
select * from vw_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `string_agg()` function,

```
select date, class2 as class, sec2 as ssec, core1 as core, string_agg(col2,' , '  order by class, sec) as group_of_family from
(select date, family, class2, sec2, core1 from table1
union all
select date, family, class2, sec2, core1 from table2
union all
select date, family, class2, sec2, core1 from table3) qry
group by date, class2, sec2, core1;
```